# Always getting Null while sending data from View to controller using @Html.ActionLink()

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

This is my view and I want to send this `id` value to the registration controller  `EditDetail` action method. But I'm always getting null.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDetails", "Registration", new { id = 10 }) |
}
```

Here is my controller. Please suggest if I need to change anything.

```
public ActionResult EditDetails(int id)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: I think your `EditDetails` and `Registration` arguments are swapped. Doesn't it go `Controller` and then `Action`? EDIT: Depends on MVC version...

Comment: yes its goes to controller action method...but the value is getting null.

Comment: When you execute your project, inspect the HTML to see how the href tag is created. it does include the querystring ?id=10 ?

Comment: ... or, depending on your route settings, a final /10 to the href?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but why not try to define the id like this

`id = 10;`

and use it like

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDetails", "Registration", id)`

Comment: Can you expand your answer with some information that explains why this change would help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong Overload method, try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDetails", "Registration", new { id = 10}, null)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: My first answer was wrong, the null was before the new { id = 10}. Plus the action and controller were wrong too. Have you tried the updated answer?